# view all students to specific student

Tags: php, mysql

sorry for the inconvenience i decide to Edit again the main prob, i have a problem about my in php-mysql, i have a page that have table of all students and i want to view them individual to view full details, can you help to what im going to do if im click the IndividualStudentView.php still i want to view the student but in particular details of student ?

```
          <thead>
                         <tr> <th hidden="">Id</th>
                               <th>ID Number</th>
                               <th>Firstname</th>
                               <th>Middlename</th>
                               <th>Lastname</th>
                               <th>Sex</th>

                       </tr>
                  </thead>


<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","enrollmentsystem");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM studentpersonalinformation ORDER By Id DESC");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {

                        ?>




<tbody>
      <tr>
          <td hidden=""><?php echo $row['Id']?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['IDNumber']?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['Firstname']?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['Middlename']?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['Lastname']?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['Sex']?></td>
                         <td>
                             <a href="IndividualViewStudent.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Option</a>

                         </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>




          <?php
          }

        mysqli_close($con);


                     ?>     
        </table>`
```

Comment: `<a href="IndividualViewStudent.php?Id=<?php echo $row['Id']?>" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Option</a>`

Comment: php var names are case sensitive so `$id= $_Get['Id'];` not equal to `$id= $_GET['Id'];`

Comment: Please show the code in `IndividualViewStudent.php` - im sure part of the issue is what i pointed out above, but there are probably other problems

Comment: " can you help to what im going to query to make view only specific
student?"

How you want to view student? Student who have particular name, Id number.?

Comment: whole details of informatioin

Comment: You want to make query in a database to for whole details?

Comment: i have table of all students and but when i click the button i want to view only one student to view his/her student information

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `studentid` to IndividualViewStudent.php.

```
<a href="IndividualViewStudent.php?Id=<?php echo $row['Id']?>" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Option</a>
```

Comment: php var names are case sensitive so `$id= $_Get['Id'];` not equal to `$id= $_GET['id'];`

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you have a table for all students and when you click the button/table of a particular student it should display the information about that student only.

I think you can do this in a two way.

1. On the same page

When you click table of a particular student, it should overlay the context of whole page and display the information of that student as a `custom confirm box`. For example On Facebook when you want to see all the person who view you profile. You click see more and a Pop up is shown with the name of the all the person.

Here you can read more about [confirm box](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp).

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

2. On the other page.

As you doing, by clicking the button/table to view IndividualViewStudent.php for individual details. For this,  you have to pass the some information about the student such as student id to other page by any method GET OR POST.
Then we should use this id to make mysqli Query to find the particular student. 
Then fetch the data and display it on the page in a formatted style.

GET METHOD: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

POST METHOD: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php